# Why my .Appx File is not Showing in Install Local Apps Menu in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating Windows Phone App Pakcage for Windows Phone 8.1. It is creating a MyApp.appx file. I simply copied that file into my phone and open store there is a option Install Local Apps but nothing is showing.

On the other side when i download any .appx file from windows phone store and copying it in to my phone. Go to Store and open Install Local Files. App is showing

Why My app is not showing. Is i am not creating my package rightly ??

My app is installing correctly through windows phone deployment tool.

Comment: Apps in the store pass certification and probably are signed in some way. In this case you are probably allowed to install only signed apps. As you are developer you are allowed to install apps that not from the store on your registered phone, but you need a tool to deploy them - VS or the mentioned WPDeploymentTool.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the AppX file into the root dir of your SD card. Now you see the app in store under ["Install Local Apps"](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card).

If the Appx file was not downloaded from the Store, you have to connect your phone to the PC, [register your phone as a developer phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn614128.aspx). Now run the Application Deployment tool to deploy the app to the device:

[image]

Comment: I am doing the Same. Store Dowloaded Files are showing but my appx file is not showing. I Created many. Even i download sample project from msdn and create appx file but its not showing

Comment: ok, I added the steps to deploy as to the phone via the Application Deployment tool

Comment: I have the same problem: I can deploy my app on my Lumia from VS 2015 running 8.1 fine, but if I generate a release `.appx` using msbuild, it doesn't show up in "install local apps" once copied to the phone. However, installing using the Application Deployment Tool works.